# How to make text and textInput in react native not overlay

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Hello guys so I'm trying to learn react native and I wanted to make a to do list app. I manage to make the app to add some tasks but if I add to many task it will cover the
text input button. Anyone know how to fix this ? so it will not overlap ?

```
import Task from '../components/Task';

const Home = () => {
    const [task, setTask] = useState();
    const [taskItems, setTaskItems] = useState([]);

    const handleAddTask = () =>{
        Keyboard.dismiss();
        setTaskItems([...taskItems, task])
        setTask(null);
    }
    
    const completeTask = (index) =>{
        let itemsCopy = [...taskItems];
        itemsCopy.splice(index, 1);
        setTaskItems(itemsCopy);
    }

    return (

        <View>
            <Image style={styles.homeLogo} source={require('../assets/logo.png')}/>
            <Text style={styles.homeText}>Hello, Welcome Back!</Text>

            <View style={styles.taskItem}>
                {taskItems.length > 0 ? (taskItems.map((item, index) => {
                       return (
                            <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={() => completeTask(index)}>
                                <Task text={item} /> 
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                       )
                    })) :

                    (
                        <View style={styles.noItemWrapper}>
                            <Text style={styles.noItem1}>There are no task</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.noItem2}>Make your first reminder</Text>
                        </View>
                    )
                }
            </View>

            <KeyboardAvoidingView 
                behavior={Platform.OS === "Android" ? "padding" : "height"}
                style = {styles.writeTaskContainer}
            >
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholder={'Write your task'} value={task} onChangeText={text => setTask(text)}/>

                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleAddTask() }>
                    <View style={styles.ButtonWrapper}>
                        <Text style={styles.addText}>+</Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>

            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: How does it look like and your expected result? Probably just need using `position: "absolute"`

Answer (score 0):

Use ScrollView instead of View.

```
<ScrollView style={styles.taskItem}>
```